# VHDL bit aggregation

Tags: vector, vhdl, bit

I have a VHDL design question.
I have N similar entities which take some input and each of them generates
an STD_LOGIC output.

Example:

```
entity example1 is
begin
    ...
    result_1 : out std_logic;
end example1;

entity example2 is
begin
    ...
    result_2 : out std_logic;
end example2;

...
```

I am looking for a way to aggregate all those single bit results in one UNSIGNED(N - 1 downto 0) result signal V such that V(i) = result_i holds.

Currently, my approach looks like this:

```
entity ResultAggregation is
   port (
      result_1 : in std_logic;
      result_2 : in std_logic;
      aggregate_results : out unsigned(1 downto 0)
   );
end ResultAggregation;

architecture Behavioral of ResultAggregation is
begin
   aggregate_results <= result_2 & result_1;
end Behavioral;
```

I find this approach rather clumsy. What I am looking for is a more automated solution,
for example that I can provide the number N such that the appropriate pins are generated.

I know this is a rather generic question, but if somebody knows a clever solution please
let me know.

Thanks in advance, 
Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions would be to omit the `ResultAggregation` entity and only define a `aggregate_results` signal on the same level as your `example1`, `example2`, etc. entities. You could then instantiate these entities as

```
i_example1 : entity work.example1
port map (
    ...
    result_1 => aggregate_results(0));

i_example2 : entity work.example2
port map (
    ...
    result_2 => aggregate_results(1));
```

You could make the width of the `aggregate_results` vector a generic on the level where you instantiate the `example1` etc. entities.

The only way you can get a generic number of pins would be to define your `ResultsAggregation` entity as

```
entity ResultAggregation is
   generic (
       N_RESULTS : integer
   );
   port (
      results : in std_logic_vector(N_RESULTS-1 downto 0);
      aggregate_results : out std_logic_vector(N_RESULTS-1 downto 0)
   );
end ResultAggregation;
```

But then this entity would only contain the statement `aggregate_results <= results` which makes this entity pointless.

Answer (score 0):

use a for/generate statement if blocks are identical:

```
n_examples: for i in 0 to (N-1) generate
   inst_example: example_entity
      port map(
          ...
          result => V(i);
      );
end generate n_examples;
```

if blocks have similar entity but different funcitonality, you can still use this approach:

```
...  
inst_ex1: example1 
port map(
    ...,
    result_1 => V(1)
);

inst_ex2: example2 
port map(
    ...,
    result_2 => V(2)
);
....
```